# How to pause PerformSelector from execution?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having serious problem whenever I pause the game, since most of my `performSelector:` has delay, so it will not execute immediately, but thing goes bad if I'm pausing the game then the `performSelector` is still calling... How should I overcome this?

I know there is one function under `NSObject` to cancel all the requests but that's not really what i'm looking for because I want the method to continue execute if the player resume the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [cocos2d Best Practices](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices) you should not use `performSelector:afterDelay` directly but use cocos2d scheduler instead:

> - Try **NOT** to use Cocoa’s NSTimer. Instead use cocos2d’s own scheduler.
> - If you use cocos2d scheduler, you will have:
>
>   - automatic pause/resume.
>   - when the CCLayer (CCScene, CCSprite, CCNode) enters the stage the timer will be automatically activated, and when it leaves the stage it will be automatically deactivated.
>   - Your target/selector will be called with a delta time

Here's how you schedule your method (assuming self is a `CCNode`):

```
[self schedule: @selector(tick2:) interval:0.5];
```

Don't forget to unschedule it in `-tick2:` if you want to call it once.